# Simple Send/Receive MultiThread always giving null exception

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I just beginner to code a simple multi Thread app for academic purpose.

I divided the code in 3 classes as specified by my supervisor.

A ResponseQueue : contains a queue and 2 methods for insert/remove.

A Sender : that will try to send, A receiver that will be receiving the message.

A Message class that contains an id and a response (String).

A Junit test is used to see if the code works: "TestSendReceiveFromResponseQueue"

The code is the following :

```
public class ResponseQueue {

private ResponseQueue() {
}

private BlockingQueue<Message> queue = new SynchronousQueue<Message>();

public synchronized Message poll() {
    Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    Message response = null;

    try {
        response = queue.take();
        if (response != null) {
            return response;
        } else {
            log.error("null");
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}

public synchronized boolean push(Message response) {
    Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    System.out.println("tryin");
    try {
        queue.put(response);
        return true;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;

}

private static class LazyHolder {
    private static final ResponseQueue INSTANCE = new ResponseQueue();
}

public static ResponseQueue getInstance() {
    return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
}

}



public class TestSendReceiveFromResponseQueue extends TestCase{
    ResponseQueue respQueue;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        respQueue= ResponseQueue.getInstance();
    }

    class Receiver implements Runnable {
        Message message;
        ArrayList<Message> messageList = new ArrayList< Message>();


        @Override
        public void run() {
            message = null;
            while(true){

                message = respQueue.poll();
                messageList.add(message);


            }
            }

    }

    class Sender implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Message msg = new Message();
        msg.setResponse("test");



        respQueue.push(msg);

        }

    }

    public void test() {
        Receiver r = new Receiver();
        new Thread(r).start();

        Sender s = new Sender();
        new Thread(s).start();


        assertEquals(false, r.messageList.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

I don't know why it's always giving a nullpointerException or an infinite loop.
Any help would be welcome.

edit : corrected the code thanks to the useful answers, still it's always giving me false.
thanks.

Comment: In `Receiver#run` you declare a local variable called `message`. It looks like you meant to use the field called `message` instead.

Comment: Thanks, corrected it but i still get an infinite loop with the code.

Comment: Do you know which loop is not ending when you want it to?

Comment: here : while(r.message==null)
  {
   
  }

Answer (score 1):

In ResponseQueue.push:

```
if(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    done = true;
    return true;
}
```

It's possible your receiver thread is grabbing the message as soon as it's put on the queue and by the time the sender gets to this check the queue is empty again causing it to loop and repost the message.

Assuming you intend to have the sender wait for the message to be received, this check should be removed and you should replace the line above calling 
`queue.add` with `queue.put` as this does exactly that check for you in a correct thread-safe manner.

Your receiver should also be using `queue.take` and not `queue.poll`, the `take` method will wait until a message is available so you can remove the loop checking if the message is null.

Finally your receiver is running an infinite `while(true)` loop and once it's received a message the first thing it does is go back round the loop and set the message to null again.  It is possible this is occurring before the test gets a chance to check the message field so your test ends up in an infinite loop.

A simple solution would be to remove the `message = null;` line since you no longer need to check that if using `queue.take`.

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        message = respQueue.take(); //This will wait for a message
    }
}
```

(Note though there would still be a race-condition whereby a new message might be received before the test could look at the previous one.  A workaround here might be to store the received messages in a list.)

Comment: Thanks, corrected it, actually I intended to call the field and not the variable, but i still get an infinite loop with the code.

Comment: Do you know where it's looping?

Comment: its loops in the Testing here : while(r.message==null)
  {
   
  }

Comment: "the line above calling  queue.add with queue.push", you mean queue.put(message).
push doesnt exists.

Comment: I updated the main post with the modifications i made, it's still giving me false in the test.

Comment: See my further edits about using `queue.take` in the receiver and not resetting the message to null every time.

Comment: Okey :) 
but I'm already using queue.take() in the poll() method.

Answer (score 0):

In your `poll()` method you are looping until `response == null` and this loop is in a `synchronized` block. When you use the `synchronized` key word in java, a lock is obtained on the object that this method is being called from. This lock is only released when the thread exits the method. This means that when your `Sender` calls `push()` (also a synchronized method) it will wait for the lock to be come available before entering. This will cause a deadlock and result in your infinite loop. Try using `synchronized(this){...}` only on the code that needs to be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

> still it's always giving me false. thanks.

first of all there is no synchronization at all on Receiver.messageList
but you have 2 threads accessing it (the 'receiver' thread and the thread running the testcase). Without proper synchronization you might or might not end up in a situation where the junit-thread does'nt event see the changes the receiver thread made. you have to synchronize on that.

apart from that you probaly have a timing problem because you have no guarantee the the 'receiver' thread did anything when the unittest-thread executes the `assertEquals(false, r.messageList.isEmpty());` statement. the simplest solution would be to 'waste some time' before executing the assert, although this is probably not very robust.